# What are some good ways to set a path in a Multi-OS supported Python script

Tags: python

When writing a Python script that can be executed in different operating system environments (Windows/*nix), what are some good ways to set a path? In the example below I would like to have the logfiles stored in the logs folder under the current directory. Is this an acceptable approach (I'm rather new to Python) or are there better ways to achieve this? Thanks

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    logdir=('%s\\logs\\') % (os.getcwd())
else:
    logdir=('%s/logs/') % (os.getcwd())

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S',
    filename='%slogfile.log' % (logdir),
    filemode='a')
```

Comment: Note that MS OSes have accepted the forward slash as a path separator for a long time (it's the command line shells that have issued with it).  "/" also works on OS X. I don't know about OpenVMS.  The most portable approach is what Ryan mentions, which will work on all OSes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely have a look at `os.path`.  It contains many of the "safe" cross-OS path manipulation functions you need.  For example, I've always done this in the scenario you're outlining:

```
os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'logs')
```

Also note that if you want to get the path separator, you can use:

```
os.path.sep
```

This will yield '\\' on Windows, and '/' on Linux, for example.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I ended up with the following based on your advice:

os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__scriptname__)), 'logs') + (os.sep) 

This yielded the proper path with the correct slash at the end of the path.

Answer (score 2):

First, always use os.path for path manipulation.

More importantly, all paths should be provided in configuration files.

For logging, use the [fileConfig](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.fileConfig) function.

For everything else, be sure to have a configuration file or command-line parameter or environment variable.